# Python динамическая картинка в canvas

Tags: python, canvas

пишу игру жизнь, проблема в обработке значений, а именно, при обработке полей, должно быть изменение картинки на изображении, но программа как бы зависает и на canvas динамически не отображаются изменения, здесь текст программы, которая анализирует поле и оживляет или убивает клетки. Что я делаю не так?))

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time


def cell(i, j, live):
    if live == 1:
        canv.create_rectangle(i * 10, j * 10, i * 10 + 10, j * 10 + 10, fill='black')
    if live == 0:
        canv.create_rectangle(i * 10, j * 10, i * 10 + 10, j * 10 + 10, fill='white')


def full_field():
    global field_list
    field_list = [[int(randint(0, 1)) for i in range(50)] for j in range(50)]
    for i in range(50):
        for j in range(50):
            if field_list[i][j] == 1:
                cell(i, j, 1)
            elif field_list[i][j] == 0:
                cell(i, j, 0)


def work_fill():
    for i in range(50):
        for j in range(50):
            if field_list[i][j] == 1:
                cell(i, j, 1)
            elif field_list[i][j] == 0:
                cell(i, j, 0)


def analise():
    count = 0
    pokolenie = 0
    while pokolenie < 2:
        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(50):
                try:
                    count += field_list[i - 1][j - 1] + field_list[i - 1][j] + field_list[i - 1][j + 1] + field_list[i][
                        j + 1] + field_list[i + 1][j + 1] + field_list[i + 1][j] + field_list[i + 1][j - 1] + \
                             field_list[i][j - 1]
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                # print(count)
                # print(i, j, field_list[i][j])
                if count < 2:
                    if field_list[i][j] == 1:
                        field_list[i][j] = 0
                elif 2 <= count <= 3:
                    if field_list[i][j] == 1:
                        pass
                    elif field_list[i][j] == 0:
                        field_list[i][j] = 1
                elif count > 3:
                    field_list[i][j] = 0
                count = 0
        work_fill()
        pokolenie += 1


root = Tk()
root.title('Game Life')
root.geometry('500x500+450+150')
canv = Canvas(root, bg='white', height=500, width=500)

file_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label='Generate', command=full_field)
file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.quit)

main_menu = Menu()
main_menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label='Start', command=analise)
main_menu.add_cascade(label='Stop')

canv.pack()
field_list = list()

root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
новое_изображение = PhotoImage( file='изображение.png')
canvas.itemconfig(объект, image = новое_изображение)
canvas.update()
```

и можно еще добавить после `canvas.update()` рядок `time.sleep(0.01)` если будете использовать этот код в цикле